# PHP Streaming very large video (> 4GB) problem

Tags: php, amazon-s3, video-streaming

I am trying to play a long video (4gb+) using an 8 MB chunk but it is not working. everything looks good with video until 2 GB size but getting problem for very large video size. Is anything I will need to optimize at PHP, Apache side, or anything needed to update in following script to support very large video?

```
<?php
require 'awss3/vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;  
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

$objectkey = '<VIDEO>.mp4'; 

$buffer = '';
$bucketname = '<BUCKETNAME>';
$key = '<KEY>';
$secret = '<SECRET_KEY>';
$region = '<REGION>';

$s3 = new S3Client([
    'region' => $region,
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => $key,
        'secret' => $secret,
    ]
]);

$s3->registerStreamWrapper();


$context = stream_context_create(array(
    's3' => array(
        'seekable' => true
    )
));

// get the file's mime type to send the correct content type header
$path = "s3://$bucketname/$objectkey";

header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK');
header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

$options = array(
    "ssl" => array(
        "verify_peer" => false,
        "verify_peer_name" => false,
    ),
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$handle = fopen($path, 'rb', false, $context);

$chunkSize = 1024 * 1024 * 8;
$buffer = '';

ob_start();
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $buffer = fread($handle, $chunkSize);
    echo $buffer;
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
fclose($handle);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to proxy this data through your PHP application.

Simply sign an S3 URL and let your clients load that data directly from S3.  Then, there is no load at all on your server, and no waste of bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 

Pre-Signed URL is valid for max 7 days only - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-presigned-url.html and because of that only I have decided to go with S3 Wrapper - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/feature-s3-stream-wrapper.html. At last, we have the option to generate a pre-signed URL every time a user accesses the page for playing S3 Video.
Please let us know if anything we needed to change/configure at PHP/Apache server-side to support large video with Stream Wrapper.